# Very large Jar files and FAT32

Tags: file, jar, fat32, bigdata

I am doing some analysis for a chunk of a desktop app we're working on.

One requirement is that it be able to do i/o of some legacy file formats, which in practice are running as large as 800Mb each. An import might reasonably be expected to be on the order of 5Gb in size.

Ideally, I'd just stick whatever files I want into a jar file, sign the thing, and send it off for re-import at a some later time.

But our app must support XP Pro (FAT32), which has a max file size limit of around 4Gb, from what I can tell.

Must I break my data up into multiple chunks? (And therefore take on the complexity of keeping track of what's going on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no other way of storing 5GB of data on FAT32 than splitting it in chunks.

Write a routine that will deal with archives of more than 4GB, i.e. split and merge. Encapsulate it in some util class or util file and call it from your save/load method.

Answer (score 0):

The max file size on fat 32 is 4gb (actually 4Gb - 2bytes), so if you have to use it and your single file is over that you will have to split it.